# How to rename a trigger?

Tags: basics

Does anyone know how to rename an Apex class or trigger in Salesforce?
When I try to refactor it in the Force.com IDE, it tells me that renaming isn't supported via the IDE. [In the wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Miscellaneous) it says:

> You cannot rename classes or triggers in Eclipse. You must go into
>   Salesforce and rename the class/trigger in the code itself.

But how is this done? When I log in to my org and go Setup > Develop > Apex Triggers, I would expect some link or button that says Edit or Rename or the like:
[image: Apex trigger listing]

Also, I couldn't find any way to rename an Apex class or trigger via the Developer Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a sandbox, you can take the following steps:

1. Create a changeset to deploy the trigger to the sandbox from production.
2. In sandbox, rename the trigger.
3. Create a changeset to deploy the trigger to production from sandbox.

If you do not have a sandbox, or do not feel like using a Sandbox, create a trigger with the new intended name on the correct SObject, copy the code from the old trigger to the new trigger, delete the old trigger, and save the new trigger.

Comment: OK thanks. I was hoping there was a quicker way that I didn't know of.

Comment: @sfdcfox are you sure that this method works and not create a new Trigger?

Comment: Anyone tested this?

Comment: @NSjonas I know that this used to work. Are you having problems with it? Also, there's a nice metadata API function "[renameMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_renameMetadata.htm)" that you may be interested in trying out. I don't have a production org I can test on though.

Comment: I don't have a prod org to really test it out on either (why I asked instead).... I guess I could deploy a new dummy object and delete it after in one of my client orgs.

Wasn't aware of renameMetadata either, looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new one and delete the old. Renaming cannot be done as far as I know. Also, you cannot change the sobject on which the trigger fires once you've set it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the *triggername* and the apex name in the code window will change accordingly.

Example:
trigger TestTrigger on Contact (After Insert)

becomes ...

trigger MyTestTrigger on Contact (After Insert)

Comment: You can't do this in Production, however, as you're not allowed to directly modify code in Production in the Developer Console. This is why my answer recommends copying to a Sandbox and back.